# Combine 2 functions for submitting a form and opening a div

Tags: javascript, forms

I am not an expert in javascript. I have the problem of merging the following 2 functions and having them run at the same time.
The first allows you to send an onclick form and place the products in a cart.

```js
$('#button').on('click',function(){
$('#form').submit();
});
```

The second opens a right side div that displays the shopping cart.

```js
body.on( 'click', '.js_addtc , .single_add_to_cart_button', function ( e ) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  let mini_cart_block$ = $( '#nt_cart_canvas' ),
      btn$ = $( this );
   
  if ( mini_cart_block$.length !== 0 ) {
    btn$.addClass( 'loading' );

    if ( $.magnificPopup && $.magnificPopup.instance.isOpen ) {
      $.magnificPopup.close();
    }

    if ( $( body ).hasClass( 'pside_opened' ) ) {
      $( body ).closeMenu();
    }

    if ( body.hasClass( 'cart_pos_dropdown' ) ) {
      setTimeout( () => {
        $( 'html, body' ).animate( { scrollTop : 0 }, 'slow', () => {
          mini_cart_block$.addClass( 'current_hover' );
          btn$.removeClass( 'loading' );
        });
      }, 500 );
    } else {
      setTimeout( () => {
        btn$.openMenu( mini_cart_block$ );
        btn$.removeClass( 'loading' );
      }, 500 );
    }
  }
});
```

Is it possible to combine the two functions and make sure that the product is added to the cart and then the right side div opens automatically? Can it be done or am I out of the way? Thank you!

this is the form

```html
<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php echo DOCROOT; ?>cart_update.php" />
<button  style="margin-right:20px;" type="submit" data-time="6000" data-ani="shake" id="button" class="single_add_to_cart_button" >
<span class="txt_add ">Aggiungi al Carrello</span></button>
</form>
```

this is the right side div

```html
<div id="nt_cart_canvas" class="nt_fk_canvas dn">
    <div class="nt_mini_cart nt_js_cart flex column h__100 btns_cart_1">
        <div class="mini_cart_header flex fl_between al_center">
            <div class="h3 fwm tu fs__16 mg__0">Il tuo carrello</div>
            <i class="close_pp pegk pe-7s-close ts__03 cd"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGsj9.png)

Comment: It is a bit out of context. Can you provide snippet of html. Or more concretely does the element with `id="button"` have also `class="single_add_to_cart_button"` attribute?

Comment: Thanks for your interest I entered what you requested.

Comment: Please try to delete your answers and add edit your question. It helps to clarity.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see both event listeners targets the same element. So you can just try to combine the content of functions.

```js
$('#button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#form').submit();

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let mini_cart_block$ = $('#nt_cart_canvas'),
        btn$ = $(this);
    if (mini_cart_block$.length !== 0) {
        btn$.addClass('loading');
        if ($.magnificPopup && $.magnificPopup.instance.isOpen) {
            $.magnificPopup.close();
        }
        if ($(body).hasClass('pside_opened')) {
            $(body).closeMenu();
        }
        if (body.hasClass('cart_pos_dropdown')) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 'slow', () => {
                    mini_cart_block$.addClass('current_hover');
                    btn$.removeClass('loading');
                });
            }, 500);
        } else {
            setTimeout(() => {
                btn$.openMenu(mini_cart_block$);
                btn$.removeClass('loading');
            }, 500);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Now he adds the product to the cart but he doesn't open the div.

Comment: I am not a jQuery expert. So I can't help you any more without working example.

Comment: ok thanks a lot anyway.